# Python f-strings: Alternative to { } curly brackets

Tags: python, string, syntax, f-string

My keyboard does not include the characters { }.

Is there an alternative to f-strings that will allow me to combine a string and variables in one go without using those curly brackets?

```
name = input(what is your name?)

print(f"My name is {name}")
```

I've tried researching but cannot find an alternative this far.

Comment: Get a different keyboard (layout): having curly brackets is **indispensable** when programming (in Python, or generally). Not just for f-strings. I’d generally recommend using an English (international) keyboard layout for programming, even if you are not writing English text otherwise: all modern operating systems allow switching keyboard layouts effortlessly.

Comment: @mkrieger1 That isn’t the same question. OP is using a roundabout description, but their actual question is “how do I work with a fundamentally inadequate tool”, and the question you’ve linked has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The duplicate question lists several alternatives for f-strings which do not involve curly braces.

Comment: @mkrieger1 That solves *one* of OP’s issues but not all, and not the most pressing one. So it isn’t even addressing (all of) the symptoms (and even if it did that would be a proverbially bad solution).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Then they should ask a different question.

Comment: You need { } for Python Dictionaries and Sets.

Comment: I want to know what keyboard layout doesn't have braces. Such a thing would be utterly hopeless for Python, C, C++, C#, Java and probably other languages that I can't be bothered to think about. @BCA profile indicates that she's from Portugal and one might imagine that she uses a Portuguese keyboard which **does** include braces. I'm beginning to think this is spam

Comment: @DarkKnight I'm a very recent learner of the world of programming, so this far I haven't needed it. Also, yes, my keyboard is Portuguese and no, it does not show those brackets. It's a Macbook, for context.

Comment: What do you get if you press Shift+Alt+8 and Shift+Alt+9?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is probably [printf-style string formatting](https://printf-style%20String%20Formatting).

```py
>>> 'string: %s, decimal: %d' % ('huh', 2)
'string: huh, decimal: 2'
```

Also check out [template strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings), they are a bit more complex, but also clearer.

```py
>>> from string import Template
>>> s = Template('string: $huh, decimal: $two')
>>> s.substitute(huh='huh', two=2)
'string: huh, decimal: 2'
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should think about buying new keyboard :D

But in your case you have some alternatives:

```py
name = input("What is your name?")
output = "My name is %s" % name
print(output)
```

```py
name = input("What is your name?")
output = "My name is " + name
print(output)
```